# Angular 2 different views based on Desktop or Mobile

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm working on web site, that has slight different functionality based on version desktop/mobile.

I tried to apply it via @View, but it looks like this decorator is now deprecated.
Please, advise me best practice, how to implement this feature in Angular 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ng2-responsive` package should cover your needs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-responsive

I haven't used it extensively yet, but it seems to be doing a decent job.

`@View` was merged into `@Component` (ages ago). `@Component` should be the only decorator you need.

Comment: ngx-responsive is now deprecated. last update was 11 feb 2020

Answer (score 8):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: "./" + (window.screen.width > 900 ? 
                     "my-component.desktop.html" : 
                     "my-component.mobile.html"),
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.css']
})
```

Comment: Angular2 uses server-side rendering, so this won't work since the @Component decorator won't have access to window https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/

Comment: You can use window.innerWidth   =instead of window.screen.width

Comment: The difference between mobile and desktop is not (only/so much) the screen resolution, but the gesture support. You can have Windows 8 or 10 in tablet mode, you still want to serve the "mobile" version.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment the best to replace `@View` decorator is using an `*ngIf` like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isMobile">
    modile stuff
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isMobile">
    desktop stuff
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example. I mean where to get "isMobile" ?

Comment: You create this property in the TS file based off screen width