# angular 2 set different template for desktop and mobile

Tags: angular

I'm building an app and I would like that some of my components will use different template and style based on user device (Desktop or mobile).
I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440694/angular-2-different-views-based-on-desktop-or-mobile) but I would like that the check up will be on an environment variable and not on screen width and I prefer not to use'd third party lib for it.

I've tried to do something like

```
templateUrl: environment.platform == platformEnum.mobile ? './mobileView.html' : './desktopView.html'
```

But i'm getting an error that environment is not defined.

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    productionLevel: 0,
    platform: platformEnum.mobile
};
```

Is there a way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: is it actually defined?

Comment: Is it not easier and better to make it with help of CSS? Just use the `@media` and then you can define different styles for devices/sreen sizes you want.

Comment: It's defined. I use this variable in my build process. I've added it into the original question.
 I prefer to do it without media query. I want to base only on the environment variable.

Comment: Still no answer after one year? Also interested in this.